# What is the best way to check each link of a website?

Tags: java, html, web-crawler

I want to create a crawler that follows each link of a site and check the URL to see if it works. Now my code opens the URL using `url.openStream()`.

So what is the best way to create a crawler?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495289/what-is-a-good-java-web-crawler-library

Comment: I don`t want to use any program, I want to code it myself, I would use something like the php html dom, or code it myself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a HTML parser like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org).

```
Set<String> validLinks = new HashSet<String>();
Set<String> invalidLinks = new HashSet<String>();

Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com").get();
Elements links = document.select("a");

for (Element link : links) {
    String url = link.absUrl("href");

    if (!validLinks.contains(url) && !invalidLinks.contains(url)) {
        try {
            int statusCode = Jsoup.connect(url).execute().statusCode();

            if (200 <= statusCode && statusCode < 400) {
                validLinks.add(url);
            } else {
                invalidLinks.add(url);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            invalidLinks.add(url);
        }
    }
}
```

You may want to send a HEAD instead inside that loop to make it more efficient, but then you'll have to use `URLConnection` instead as Jsoup by design doesn't support it (a HEAD returns no content).

Comment: sounds great but I have 1 more question: how can I include or import jsoup ?

Comment: Uh, just put the JAR file in the classpath. It's not different from other JARs. If you're using an IDE like Eclipse, just drop it in your project's root folder, then rightclick and choose *Add to build path*. If you're doing plain `javac/java`, just add path to JAR file to `-cp` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Use the internal link analyzer tool to analyze the links search engine spiders can detect on a specific page of your website. Search ... Best practices internal links. Number of links: Back in 2008, Matt Cutts (head of Google's Web-spam team) recommended limiting the number of links to a maximum of 100 links per page.

Comment: It should have been a comment